# Unable to import 'numpy'pylint(import-error)

Tags: python

I was following the tutorial of programming the Monty hall problem in python and all these errors came up and I've looked through the tutorial multiple times and still don't know what I've done wrong.

This is where all these errors came up in the same order

```
Unable to import 'numpy'pylint(import-error) Unable to import 'matplotlib.pyplot'pylint(import-error) Unused variable 'Simulate'pylint(unused-variable)][1]
```

Here is where these errors came up  in the same order

```
Unused variable 'TakeTurn'pylint(unused-variable) Unused variable 'DisplayResults'pylint(unused-variable)][2]
```

And finally this error Instance of 'Simulation' has no 'Simulate'][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sz5q2.png)

Comment: Did you redefine import mistakenly ?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to install those packages with pip before importing them. If not installed python would look for the package a not find it. Then you get errors.
Check if those packages are installed on your machine.

Like pip install matplotlib